# Build folder location in XCODE 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, xcode4.2

I am using XCODE 4.2 & when I build my project I do not see libMyProject.a file under "Products" folder turning black even though my build is successful.

Where do these .a files gets stored. With 3.2.6, build folder used to be inside my project workspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build it for device and not simulator for it to become black. But if you have only build it for the simulator, it will remain red.

As for the location of the binary, it is located in the **Derived Data folder** in the subfolder specified in **Pre-Configuration Build Products Path** which by default has the values **build/Debug-iphoneos** and **build/Release-iphoneos**

**EDIT**

You can change the product name in the Build settings of your target by modifying the value of **Product Name** in the **Packaging** group.

Comment: Any idea how do we change the target library name in XCODE 4.2. I am building my project on target X & getting libX.a file. I want name it libY.a instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you build, check out the Log navigator (cmd-7). Read the log for your build: it will contain the full path to the build product.

Still, it should show up as a Product in Xcode...

Answer (score 2):

They normally get put into /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{PROJECT_NAME_AND_RANDOM_CRAP}/Build/Products/{BUILD_TYPE}/{PROJECT_NAME}.app

Answer (score 1):

You have to build it for device and not simulator. If you build it for device then its color would be red and you does not get project.app file. To get project.app file you have to build in device(iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch). After build in device the color of project.app file will change to black.
Another procedure you can follow if you want to get only .app file not under Products folder.For that goto Products->Archive->Share then save. It will generate .ipa file. By changing app to zip and unzip the file you get the .app file.